# IIS 10 web.config throwing 500 for uploaded files such as images, pdf, docx

Tags: wordpress, iis, web-config, mime-types

This is my web.config on IIS10 and I am hosting wordpress site on it which I have migrated from other hosting.

For existing uploads, when I open a file in browser, it is displayed, but for new uploads, I get Internal server error 500. I think it might have to do something with web.config, but not sure. Do you think I have something missing there? Or is this a wordpress issue?

Url I test where I get 500 is like this: https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/test.pdf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1-1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{URL}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PHP_via_FastCGI1" />
            <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is the error I am getting:
From logs:

```
2021-01-29 13:42:17 192.168.1.41 GET /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/v2_1.jpg - 443 - 192.168.1.41 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/87.0.4280.141+Safari/537.36 - 500 50 5 54
```

[image]

Comment: You have to show a complete error page or FRT trace log, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Otherwise, no one can help much.

Comment: Can you get the details of the error? There are also some solutions for 500 errors in the Microsoft documentation, you can refer to it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-error-500-when-you-visit-web-site#:~:text=of%20the%20problem.-,More%20information,time%20the%20error%20is%20returned.&text=This%20problem%20occurs%20because%20the,directory%20of%20the%20requested%20location.

Comment: @LexLi I have added error message.

Comment: What is "Imported Rule 1" for? You can try to delete it.